# Toggle table header class on click

Tags: jquery

How can I toggle the color of the header to only set it to red on the currently selected column header? It currently only stays on and does not go off when another header is clicked.

```js
$(".numeric").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("numeric-active");
});
```

```css
.numeric-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="container cf">
  <thead class="cf">
    <tr>
      <th class="numeric">amount <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
      <th class="numeric">case <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
      <th class="numeric">field 3 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
      <th class="numeric">field 4 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
      <th class="numeric">location <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
      <th class="numeric">date <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="verdicts">
    <tr>
      <td data-title="amount" class="amount">8,570,000.00<span class="result"></span></td>
      <td data-title="case">title</td>
      <td data-title="practice area">area</td>
      <td data-title="user">Bob jones</td>
      <td data-title="location">Orlando, FL</td>
      <td data-title="date">Mar 6, 2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="amount" class="amount">$447,115<span class="result"></span></td>
      <td data-title="case">Another title</td>
      <td data-title="practice area">area</td>
      <td data-title="user">Joe Smith</td>
      <td data-title="location">Orlando, FL</td>
      <td data-title="date">Mar 6, 2017</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by just removing the class from every other element on the click event, here's a quick example with the related jsFiddle.

```
$(".numeric").click(function() {
    $(".numeric").removeClass('numeric-active');
    $(this).toggleClass("numeric-active");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrdag8bk/3/

Comment: No problem, do not hesit to accept my answer as a solution.